# Displaying lists underneath each other with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a problem with displaying lists that flow neatly with each other to display data.  Here is what I am trying to base my lists from: http://www.about.com/#!/explore-topics/

I've ripped through the style sheet and I can't find out how they are making this happen.  I was wondering if someone would be able to shine some light on this, I've been ripping my hair out trying to replicate the same thing and I can't make it happen.  I think this may be a Javascript thing, but I am not exactly sure.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From their css:

```
#explore-topics .viewport {
-moz-column-width: 216px;
-webkit-column-width: 216px;
column-width: 216px;
width: 7910px;
}
```

They are using CSS3 column definition. Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp